# What options are there for indexing my filesystem?

Tags: 10.10, files, search, indexing, metadata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Ubuntu have an alternative to OS X's Spotlight?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6135/does-ubuntu-have-an-alternative-to-os-xs-spotlight)

Wondering what people are using to index and search their file systems. I'm looking for something with low resource usage, but with capability of indexing a large number of files in my /home folder (including documents, music, videos etc) and with a native gui for searching these. A bonus would be if it can index and search based on metadata/document content, as I don't always remember the name of the file I'm looking for (particularly when trying to find documents).

Currently running Ubuntu 10.10. I was previously using gnome-do for quick file access which was fantastic, but it wouldn't let me index my entire /home folder (said there were too many files?).

Any other good indexing options available?