# What is 'Tracker Search Tool'

Tags: tracker

[image]

In the picture above see the icon of magnifying glass.
I didn't have this icon before, It is indexing my files. Any idea what is it, I have maverick installed on 2 machines and both of them now have this icon.

When I click on it and search for some file, on the title bar it says "Tracker Search Tool"

It is really cool to search for files but I would like to know that if it is one of the default app, even though it was not there before nor I installed any app like this.

Comment: Nice icon theme. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/) is a search engine and metadata store that indexes your files to do all sorts of interesting things. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7697/what-options-are-there-for-indexing-my-filesystem/7702#7702) for some usage basics.

It hasn't been installed by default in Ubuntu since Ubuntu 9.04; you must have installed it inadvertently. If you'll not be using it, you can remove it by removing the "tracker" package.