# Is there something similar to SpotLight ( Mac ) for Ubuntu

Tags: search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to OS X's Spotlight?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6135/alternatives-to-os-xs-spotlight)

So it's quite clear, if you don't know what SpotLight is, well, it puts an icon on your taskbar, and then you can search ( Please ignore everything else but the icon, all I want is the icon and ability to search )