# `locate`-based GUI search

Tags: gnome, search, locate

I've been using `locate` on the command line quite a bit lately and it's really nice for finding files quickly.  The index is regenerated every night, so  it doesn't have the latest files, but it's ridiculously fast for finding anything else.

So, I'm wondering:  does there exist any GUI app to help with searching my files that is based on locate and would run as fast?  Even cooler would be a plug for the Gnome dash or something.

Does anything like that exist?  I like how fast locate is, can I do it in the a GUI?

Comment: If you run a quick `sudo updatedb` before the `locate`, your database is up to date and it only takes up to very few seconds, depending on how much changed since the last update. I can't name you a GUI for it though.

Comment: Have you tried `catfish` ?

Comment: Looks duplicate of [What are the alternatives to OS X's Spotlight?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6135/what-are-the-alternatives-to-os-xs-spotlight).